# Transferring value from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that can allow user to enter upto 100 rows of information and when they click submit button script will enter that data into master data spreadsheet.

I have written script that works and transfers data to master data sheet and I am using openbyID to open target sheet.

The problem is that without access to master data sheet user can not open the sheet to add data. if there is a way to add data to a spreadsheet without having access to that spreadsheet would be ideal for my needs.

Please let me know if that is possible.

Once again I am currently using OpenByID to open spreadsheet and would like allow users to add data to master spreadsheet without direct access to spreadsheet.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you
Khokhar

My Code:

```
Sorry I am not sure how to write my script as web app.
```

please see below my script.. can you please help me explain how to change it to work as web app?

Thank you

```
function CopyDataToMaster() {
  var inf = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inf_sheet = inf.getSheetByName("Info");
  var tt_key = inf_sheet.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var SiteName = inf_sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var d = new Date();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tt = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tt_key);

  var ss_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
  var tt_sheet = tt.getSheetByName("Master-Data-Sheet");
  var FilledBy = ss_sheet.getRange("C5").getValue();

  var tt_last_row = tt_sheet.getLastRow();
  var tt_work_row = tt_last_row+1;

  for (var i=1; i<=100 ; i++) {
    var dDr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 2);
    var dD = dDr.getValue();
    if (dD!="") {
      var nMr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 3);
      var nM = nMr.getValue();      
      var aMr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 4);
      var aM = aMr.getValue();      
      var bWr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 5);
      var bW = bWr.getValue();      
      var bSr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 6);
      var bS = bSr.getValue();      
      var tDr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 7);
      var tD = tDr.getValue();      
      var mOr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 8);
      var mO = mOr.getValue();      
      var bOr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 9);
      var bO = bOr.getValue();      
      var dCr = ss_sheet.getRange(i+10, 10);
      var dC = dCr.getValue();

      tt_sheet.insertRowAfter(tt_work_row-1);

      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),+5.5, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,2).setValue(SiteName);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,3).setValue(FilledBy);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,4).setValue(dD);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,5).setValue(nM);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,6).setValue(aM);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,7).setValue(bW);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,8).setValue(bS);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,9).setValue(tD);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,10).setValue(mO);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,11).setValue(bO);
      tt_sheet.getRange(tt_work_row,12).setValue(dC);

      dDr.clearContent();
      nMr.clearContent();
      aMr.clearContent();
      bWr.clearContent();
      bSr.clearContent();
      tDr.clearContent();
      mOr.clearContent();
      bOr.clearContent();
      dCr.clearContent();

      tt_work_row = tt_work_row+1;
    }
  }
  Browser.msgBox("Thank you", "Information has been submitted",Browser.Buttons.OK)
}
```

Comment: Good luck with this. The answer is in the documentation, i.e. Google-Apps-Script & JavaScript documentation. ... This is more the kind of thing you would pay a programmer to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script as a web app, which can access Google documents and Spreadsheets. If you do this you can set the permissions on the script so that a user running it has your permissions rather than their own. If you have access to the master spreadsheet than your script will, but your users won't.

The details are on the [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps). Look down the page for *Permissions and WebApps*

Comment: I have added my code can you please help me guide how to create webapp.. I am not experienced at all with google scripts..

Thank you

Comment: I'm not about to rewrite your script for you. The link I gave you points to the relevant page on the Google site that should get you started. If you're not able to do it consider hiring someone.

Comment: I just wanted to give you example of what my code is and needed guidance on whether i will be able to modify my the code I have written to use as webapp for data transfer or it will be completely different. The link that you gave points to the page which explain parameters of publishing web apps but not really explaining how webapps work and how to begin writing one. Thank you for your answer though..

Answer (score 0):

Protect a sheet or two? - You can protect sheets, so some sheets can be edited and others can't. You can control who can edit which sheets. ... Also maybe use database formulas to pull the data across. Less work than writing code. Because there is a history of all edits, you can use this see all changes made to the sheets.

Comment: I am inserting value from multiple sheet to one sheet and can not have different users see information entered by anyone else. its all confidential data...